# How to pass the param with slash to repository in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

In Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/attendance/update")
public String updateAttendance(@RequestParam("caseId") String caseId) {
// Pass the case ID "ABCD/EF/01" (with splash)
```

In Repository:

```
@Query(value="SELECT personSN FROM Scheme WHERE serialNo = ':caseId'", nativeQuery=true)
String getpersonSN(@Param("caseId") String caseId);
```

Application properties:
`org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true`

SQL server is using.

I got the problem the param cannot pass to repository (:caseId). No value can be passed.

May I know how to fix it?

Comment: Remove the `'` from `:caseId` in your query. You are currently using `:caseId` as the string and it won't be replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M. Deinum is right. Remove the '' around the :caseId

```
@Query(value="SELECT personSN FROM Scheme WHERE serialNo = :caseId", nativeQuery=true)
String getpersonSN(@Param("caseId") String caseId);
```

Comment: The question doesn't mention a path-variable (nor would it work as it would only receive the last part I believe).

Comment: You are probably right. But with the RequestParam it doesn't work as well

Comment: @SimonMartinelli It works fine in `RequestParam`, I've tested.